# Retrieving google result based on specific tag in html

Tags: search, google-search, google-search-api

I'm trying to google search a set of result but the result is way bigger than expected.
I looked into each page, and it turned out there are different layout sets and most of false-positives are coming from there which are not relevant from what I'm expecting.

so I'd like to confine the result just to search with a query in some specific `<div>`tags. for example,

```
<div class="content_important">
    I love foo and bar
</div>
<div class="i_dont_want_this">
    I hate foo and bar
</div>
```

and I'm looking for results for a query `foo and bar` only in `<div class="content_important">` so that the results from `<div class="i_dont_want_this">` doesn't appear on the search result.

The key is that I know how to parse the html pages, but I would like to filter them out before parsing since there can be too many results to parse out.

Comment: This is an interesting question. I'd like to ask Google whether a specific url contains a specific html tag, and stumbled over your question. Any progress?